# asp.net calender control problem

Tags: asp.net

iam using calender control in asp.net 2.0 
as it is using master pages.. iam opening a window form content pages..
on window.close it is giving me null object as its not getting form name
you help will be appreciated

code on content page:

```
<a onclick="openwindow();" ahref="#">
<img src="Images/calendar.gif" style="width: 20px; height: 20px" border=0/></a>
<input ID="Text1" runat="server" readonly="readOnly" type="text" />

function openwindow() {  
    window.open('/Calender.aspx', 'calendar_window','width=154,height=188');
}
```

code on opened window from content page

```
protected void Calender1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strjscript = "<script language='javascript'>";
        strjscript += "window.opener." + HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["formname"];
        strjscript += ".value = '" + Calender1.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'; window.close();";
        strjscript += "</script" + ">";  
        Literal1.Text = strjscript; 
    }

    protected void Calendar1_dayrender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {             
          if(e.Day.Date==DateTime.Now)
        {
            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Wondering any reason to use that calendar technique when you have other options like AJAX control toolkit Calender: http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/calendar/calendar.aspx or jQuery datepicker http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: yess as of its urgent i have to study ajax... i tried with JS script too... it gives me back value on text box which is not runat=server... how tom access tht value in code behind..

Comment: i tried using ajax controltoolkit.. but there r lot of errors for 2.0 its fine with 3.5

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Make sure your are point to correct path to Calendar.aspx. One issue I do see is the script you are generating. Can you explain a bit on what you want from that script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are not following [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150655/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/030202-1.aspx) but not exactly what it is doing.

Points to note:

1: Make sure you are naming your form

2: Pass textbox reference via querystring i.e. Calender.aspx?formname=frmCalendar.txtDate

3: Path to your calender.aspx is correct.

You are close to solution but may be you need to share your main page code as well for us.

**Edit 1** 
Ok I see now what you are saying. Add this script block to your content page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openwindow() {
        var txtid = '<%=txtDate.ClientID %>';
        var frmid = '<%=Page.Form.ClientID %>';
        var qs = "formname=" + frmid + "." + txtid;
            window.open('/Calendar.aspx?' + qs,'calendar_window', 'width=154,height=188');
        }
</script>
```

Although if possible try using jquery datepicker and you can post your code and issue if you want to go that route.

Comment: hi, this script will pass values to main form same tutorial.. but that tutorial is having a form tag .. content page dont have .. tht is where iam facing problem as when window closes it doesnt find formname.textbox to assign it .......                                                                   i have tried using this technique also jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker – but it only works with html text again i have to acces this text in code behind how to go about that.

Comment: this is my main page code.. i removed forms thing iam just closing window adding vlaue to cache.

Comment: there is problem in this code.. its taking value from window perfectly but when everi click on submit button ... it goes away and validator fires.... that means every time if any validation is missing it goes away .and iam not getting that text value in code behind....i dont know why it is happening

Comment: and other thing its does not gets empty when its readonly property is set to false .. if it sets to true i cant get in code behind.. is there some relation.. i rerad soem blogs .. in tht same problem is specified..

Comment: Yes setting readonly in markup could be an issue and you can try setting it readonly in code-behind like shown here: http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2007/05/10/112390.aspx